# Proof of continuity via Sequence Criterion?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

We are to prove that $f(x) = x$ if $x$ is rational, and $f(x) = 1 - x$ if $x$ is irrational is discontinuous for all $x$ on the interval $[0,1]$ except at $x = 1/2$.
So, I've broken the proof into two parts, proving discontinuity for all $a$, where $a$ not equal to $1/2$ is easy enough, but having trouble proving continuity at $a = 1/2$, as for practice, only allowed to use Sequential Criterion for Continuity.

So far, I have:
Let $S$ be any sequence that converges to $(1/2)$.  $F(1/2) =  1/2$ by definition.  Consider any $S_n$ in $S$, if $S_n$ is rational, then $f(S_n) = S_n$.  If $S_n$ is irrational, then $f(S_n) = 1-S_n$.

I'm stuck here, I've tried constructing sub-sequences from the rational and irrational parts of $S_n$, but once I have that both of those converge to $(1/2)$ on their own, I lack the Theorems to necessarily say that the whole $S_n$ converges to $1/2$.  Intuitively, it seems obvious that $S_n$ converges to $1/2$ based on the case for each $S_n$, but how could I hash this out via formal proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you do not need to split into two cases. Let $\epsilon >0$. Then as $s_n \to 1/2$, there is $N \in \mathbb N$ so that

$$|s_n - 1/2| < \epsilon$$

whenever $n \geq N$. Now if $s_n$ is rational, $f(s_n) = s_n$ and so

$$|f(s_n)  - f(1/2)| = |s_n - 1/2|,$$

if $s_n$ is irrational, $f(s_n) = 1-s_n$ and

$$|f(s_n) - f(1/2)| = |1-s_n - 1/2| = |1/2 - s_n| = |s_n - 1/2|$$

and whenever $n\geq N$ we have

$$|f(s_n) - f(1/2)| < \epsilon.$$

Thus the sequence $f(s_n)$ converges to $f(1/2)$. As the sequence $s_n \to 1/2$ is arbitrary, $f$ is continuous at $1/2$.

Comment: Thanks, this helps out immensely.